# What do I need to do to update my game to Google Play Billing 3?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-billing

I'm using Unity 2018.4.22 and I've installed In App Purchasing 2.2.2 from Package Manager.

When I try to upload my game to Google Play Store, it gives me this error:

> We've detected that this app is using an old version of Google Play Billing. By November 1, 2021, all app updates must use Billing Library version 3 or newer. Update to Billing Library 3 before this date.

What exactly do I need to do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your IAP version through menu Window/Unity IAP/IAP Updates... Any IAP version higher than 2.2.1 will have the v3 Google library. You'll want to use the latest Unity IAP 2.2.7 (Asset version) along with In App Purchasing library 2.2.2 (Package Manager).

Comment: you'll want to review ALL your previous builds. Remove any archived/previous versions from your Google Play test tracks, for example.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably late for this particular answer but for whom will come here later date.
"This Asset Store version is obsolete, and will be deprecated and no longer supported after June 2021."
Meaning Unity IAP will be implemented via package manager instead of the asset store.
You can check your IAP version through Package Manager/In App Purchasing
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.purchasing@3.2/changelog/CHANGELOG.html